# Tapestry5 zone doesn't update on radio button change using zoneUpdater

Tags: java, ajax, radio-button, tapestry

I've got 2 radio buttons on my Tapestry5 page and I want to update zone when value changes:

```
<t:radio t:id="allDay" t:mixins="zoneUpdater" t:event="allDayChanged" t:clientEvent="change" zone="timeRecZone"/>
<t:radio t:id="timeRestricted" t:mixins="zoneUpdater" t:event="timeRestrictedChanged" t:clientEvent="change" zone="timeRecZone"/>

<t:zone t:update="show" elementName="div" t:id="timeRecZone" id="timeRecZone">
    <t:if test="timeRestrictedSelected">
                    .
                    .
                    .
```

I'm using known zoneUpdater mixin which works fine for me with textfield at other place of my page. But here, I don't really see timeRecZone get updated, because area under the IF condition is not being shown and I don't see following statement being logged when I'm clicking radios.

```
public boolean isTimeRestrictedSelected() {
    log.info("***** isTimeRestrictedSelected...");
    return selectedTimeRestriction == TimeRestriction.TIME_RESTRICTED;
}
```

This part (change event) works though:

```
public void onAllDayChanged() {
    selectedTimeRestriction = TimeRestriction.ALL_DAY;
    log.info("***** allDayChanged called: " + selectedTimeRestriction);
}

public void onTimeRestrictedChanged() {
    selectedTimeRestriction = TimeRestriction.TIME_RESTRICTED;
    log.info("***** timeRestrictedChanged called: " + selectedTimeRestriction);
}
```

Has anybody experienced this while working with radio/zone update? Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mea culpa, solution is here:

```
public void onAllDayChanged() {
    selectedTimeRestriction = TimeRestriction.ALL_DAY;
    ajaxResponseRenderer.addRender("timeRecZone", timeRecZone);
}

public void onTimeRestrictedChanged() {
    selectedTimeRestriction = TimeRestriction.TIME_RESTRICTED;
    ajaxResponseRenderer.addRender("timeRecZone", timeRecZone);
}
```